# A few Doraemon related questions

Tags: phrases, manga

I'm reading the following Doraemon [page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnAYY.jpg) and I've got a few questions

I'll name all panels beginning from the top right, going left

In the 8th  panel: でも、これからはドラエモンがついてるから安心しな、おじいさん。

Those 2 から are both for giving the reason for something (because)?  It's a bit confusing.

In the 5th panel I don't quite get  なんだもの at the end of なにをやらせてもだめなんだもの.  Is it maybe a way of emphasizing the なにをやらせてもだめ statement?

In the 7th panel I don't get ろくなめにあわないんだ.  A deconstruction or clarification of what is what in the sentence would be much appreciated.  The rest I get, more or less.

Then, in the last panels, I don't quite understand the て after おじいさん and what he refers to by だれのこと.  Is he asking who the robot means by おじいさん?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> In the 8th panel: でも、これ**から**はドラエモンがついてる**から**安心しな、おじいさん。
>
> Those 2 から are both for giving the reason for something (because)? It's a bit confusing.

No, only the second 「から」 is for stating a reason.  "Don't you worry ***because*** Doraemon will be with you from now on, Grandpa!"

「これ**から**」 just means "***from*** now on".

> In the 5th panel I don't quite get なんだもの at the end of なにをやらせてもだめなんだもの. Is it maybe a way of emphasizing the なにをやらせてもだめ statement?

Not quite but kind of close.  This 「もの」 is like a nuanced and somewhat emotional "'cuz".  It is a colloquial sentence-ending particle for stating a reason with an amount of dissatisfaction towards the current situaton.  In real life, it is mostly kids and women who use this 「もの」.

"'Cuz you're no good at anything."

> In the 7th panel I don't get ろくなめにあわないんだ. A deconstruction or clarification of what is what in the sentence would be much appreciated. The rest I get, more or less.

It is 「ろくな[目]{め}に[遭]{あ}わないんだ。」 if one were to use kanji.

「目に遭う」 means "to experience".

「ろくな」 , all by itself, means "satisfactory" or "good", but it is often used together with a negative word as in this case -- 「ない」.　It is one of those words that are often used by native speakers but not really by Japanese-learners.

「ろくな目に遭わないんだ。」= "You don't have such good experiences." ⇒ "Bad things keep happening to you."

> Then, in the last panels, I don't quite understand the て after おじいさん and what he refers to by だれのこと. Is he asking who the robot means by おじいさん?

「て」＝「って」.  It is a quotative particle.

『おじいさん』て、だれのこと？ = "Who do you mean by 'Grandpa'?"