# What does ろくな mean here? And is こと a nominalizer here?

Tags: grammar

ほらなやっぱ他人と関わるとろくなことがねえ。

What does ろくなことがねえ。mean?
And is こと a nominalizer here?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23756/5010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ろくなこと

ろく:
禄/碌 is a prize or reward of the contribution.
陸 is a thing placed flat or satisfying.
(否定文)ろくな ... ない - good, satisfied, decent and worth telling.

All together, "The thing is not worth telling."

> ほらなやっぱ他人と関わるとろくなことがねえ。

"See, I knew when I involved other guys, no decent thing ain't happened."

Comment: まず[禄](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E7%A6%84-663263)と[碌](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%99%B8%E3%83%BB%E7%A2%8C-414007)は違う漢字ですし、この「ろくな」を碌と書くのすら宛て字であると少なくとも3つの辞書に書かれています。

Comment: 1980年代の新名解には`禄`で武士の給与と登録されています　私は金田一親子の説を信じていますし、この件を説明するにあたり全く矛盾がないので、陸の漢字を追加しました　古い引用が正しいとは限りませんが新しいオンラインの辞書にはたまに変な紛れが存在します　例)くだら(百済)ない、からくれない(韓紅)

Comment: いや、金田一親子に聞くまでもなく「禄」は武士の給与ですけど、「ろくでもない」を「禄でもない」とは(誤字とかでなければ)まず書かないと思うのですが。私が見た辞書には全部「碌でもない」の方で載っています。繰り返しますが、禄と碌は違う漢字であり、これらは違う意味の語として辞書に載っています。新明解は手元にありませんが、「碌」の方に「武士の給与」という意味があったり、両者は同じ意味の異体字だみたいな説明があったりするのでしょうか。

Comment: 俗語の語源は「やちもない」場合が多い　沢田研二や三船敏郎からロクでもないという言葉を教わった私としてはロクは稼ぎのことだと捉えられるね　新名解には　陸と禄しかなく碌の文字はない　東京の方では「ロクでもない」カタカナで表記されることが多いのは本来の漢字は不明ということでは無いだろうか　私の住んでいるところは日本の果てなので「やちもない」がその言葉として用いられる